# Conditional probability: Show that P[A|B] + P[A'|B] = 1

Tags: probability

The problem states for two events, $A, B ⊂ Ω$, show that $P[A|B] + P[A'|B] = 1$

I'm stuck on this question as there are no given probabilities to work with. Am I supposed to make up some probabilities? If not, any help on how to get started?

$$P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$
$$P(A'\mid B)=\frac{P(A'\cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(B)-P(A\cap B)}{1-P(A)}$$

Comment: This follows from the fact that $P(*|B)$ is a valid probability distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Not that $A\cap B$ and $A'\cap B$ are disjunct and their union is $B$. Now:

$$P(A\mid B)+P(A'\mid B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}+\frac{P(A'\cap B)}{P(B)}=$$

$$=\frac{P(A\cap B)+P(A'\cap B)}{P(B)}$$ $$=\frac{P((A\cap B)\cup (A'\cap B))}{P(B)}$$

$$=\frac{P( B)}{P(B)}=1$$

Answer (score 2):

Remember that P(A|B) means the probability that A occurs given that B occurs.

Let's put some examples in place of the variables.  Let A = "It is raining outside" and B = "I decide to take a walk".

Then P(A|B) is the probability that it's raining outside given that I decided to take a walk and P(A'|B) is the probability that it is not raining outside given that I decided to take a walk.

What is the sum of those probabilities?  Obviously it is 1.  It's either raining outside or it isn't.  The weather doesn't care that I decided to take a walk.